# Sorting multikey arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I've found several answers regarding sorting multidimension arrays but none are the type of array I have.

My array looks like this:

```
$data[1][1][1] = 100; // 1,1,1
$data[1][1][2] = 120; // 1,1,2 
$data[1][2][1] = 140; // 1,2,1 
// Several hundred permutations to follow.
```

To be sorted into...

```
$data[1][2][1] = 140; // 140 is higher than 120.. etc. 
$data[1][1][2] = 120;
$data[1][1][1] = 100;
```

How can I sort $data based on its value, and return as well, the keys?

2 Caveats: The dimensions are virtually unlimited and some of the array keys are strings, not just numbers.  e.g     $data[1]["type"][1] = 100;
Thank you.

Btw.. I've tried several combinations of usort with no success...

Comment: I don't see any sorting, you've just written the example the other way around. Did you mean to change the keys in the second example? Or have I missed something?

Comment: There is a change in 2nd and 3rd keys... 1,2,1...

Comment: In both examples, `[1][1][1] = 100`, `[1][1][2] = 120` & `[1][2][1] = 140`?

Comment: Yes... one is the unsorted array, the other is the "expected" sorted array.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329) which misunderstands how arrays are structured.  This question needs to be reframed so that a sensible solution can be found to resolve the overarching problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because multidemencial array has no one order. Every subarray has its own order. For example.

```
$data[1][1][1] = 100; 
$data[1][1][2] = 140; 
$data[1][2][1] = 120;
```

Should return

```
$data[1][1][1] = 100; 
$data[1][2][1] = 120; 
$data[1][1][2] = 140;
```

But whole array `$data[1][2]` should go right after or before whole `$data[1][1]` but not in the same time.

But if you want to sort values and keep keys(but structure would be different) you could use this code.

```
$data[1][1][1] = 100;
$data[1][1][2] = 140;
$data[1][2][1] = 120;

function getValue($array, array &$sortable_array = null, $keys = array())
    {
    foreach ($array as $key => $item)
        {
        $current_keys = array_merge($keys, [$key]);
        if (is_array($item))
            getValue($item, $sortable_array, $current_keys);
        else
            {
            $sortable_array[] = ['value' => $item, 'keys' => $current_keys];
            }
        }
    }

getValue($data, $sortable_array);

usort($sortable_array, function($a, $b)
    { return $a > $b ? -1 : 1; });

// print_r($sortable_array);

// debug output    
array_map(function($e)
    { echo json_encode($e) . PHP_EOL; }, $sortable_array);

//{"value":140,"keys":[1,1,2]}
//{"value":120,"keys":[1,2,1]}
//{"value":100,"keys":[1,1,1]}
```